# Problema no retorno da query

Tags: sql, asp.net, nhibernate

Estou com um problema no meu retorno da query.

```
public IList<Rota> Lista()
        {
        //* string hql = "SELECT * FROM Rota WHERE ORDER BY Km_Atual ASC";
        string hql = "SELECT Km_Atual, MAX(DtLancamento) FROM Rota GROUP BY Id";
        //* string hql = "SELECT p FROM Rota p";
        IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
        return query.List<Rota>();
        }
```

> An exception of type 'NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException' occurred in NHibernate.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: could not execute query
>
> [ select rota0_.Km_Atual as col_0_0_, MAX(rota0_.DtLancamento) as col_1_0_ from [Rota] rota0_ group by rota0_.Id ]

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que o campo que está sendo agrupado não está sendo retornado na pesquisa e também o contrário o campo que está sendo retornado na pesquisa. Por exemplo o correto seria:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(DTLANCAMENTO) FROM ROTA GROUP BY ID
```

ou

```
SELECT KM_ATUAL, MAX(DTLANCAMENTO) FROM ROTA GROUP BY KM_ATUAL
```

Podes dar uma lida nesse [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177673(v=sql.120).aspx) sobre o group by, lá tem vários exemplos de selects com muitas colunas.